# How execute method after each action only when no one exception happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying create one webservice that consumes yammer with rails, and I'm trying to return message that indicates when action was successfully executed.

```
  around_action :sendOkMessage

  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    yammerResult = YammerResult.new
    yammerResult.status = 'NOK'
    yammerResult.message = exception.inspect
    render json: yammerResult
  end
```

The problem is, around_action is always executed (even when error happens), and I don't want this.
What I want is:

- No exception raised? Run sendOkMessage, return ok message
- Exception raised? Catch exception, return nok message

Comment: Why can't you modify your around_filter to return ok.. but to ALSO catch exceptions and return nok?

Answer (score 0):

We could use a flag and toggle it, that is define an instance variable `@failed = true` in the exception block. And make the first line of the `:sendOkMessage`. To check the `@failed` flag, if its true - toggle ito false and return.

```
def sendOkMessage
  @failed = false and return unless @failed
  @failed = false
```

Comment: But, doing this, I will go against DRY right? Because, every action I will have to set @failed as false in the end. There's nothing on rails to handle it?

Comment: Since, @failed is nil if its not initialized so the first line of `sendOkMessage` would set it as `@failed = false` on its own.  So you don't have to set it to false in every function, you just have to add `@failed = true` in to your exceptions.

Comment: But I will still have to write the rescue block only to set @failed as true, right?